# How to delete an item from state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to delete items from my MERN stack app using fetch and I have successfully deleted the item in the database. However, I cannot figure out how to delete the item from state when I click the delete button. I am using the ID of the item (groupID) to delete from the database, and I'm trying to use that to delete from state as well. Right now when clicking the button the item deletes but does not disappear until i reload the page. Here is my code:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");


const [groupsState, setGroups] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { token } = useContext(LoggedInContext);


const handleClick = (groupId) => {
    function removeGroup(groupId) {
      setGroups(groupsState.filter(el => el !== groupId));
    }
    fetch("http://localhost:8181/groups/" + groupId, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Token: token
      },
      method: "DELETE"
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data)
      removeGroup(groupId);
      })



};
```

[image: Group State]

Comment: The most reliable way would be to just refetch your data. For example what if the API errors?

Comment: @BrianThompson reliable maybe, efficient? No

Comment: What does your `groupState` data look like? You have `groupsState.filter(el => el !== groupId)`, where you're comparing each group state ITSELF to the `groupId`. Perhaps you should be accessing the `id` or something in each group state? That is, something like this: `groupsState.filter(el => el.id !== groupId)`

Comment: @klaurtar1 what does `groupsState` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're set on removing it in JavaScript, you'll just need to specify the id key in your filter

```js
setGroups(groupsState.filter(el => el.id !== groupId));
```

That's assuming it's called id, otherwise just change it to what your id key is.

Comment: Figured the same, although the initial state is an object which suggests possibly a map.

Comment: That's true. I didn't notice that at first. I'm assuming they're changing data types later on or they would have asked a question about filter not being a function, but thats just an assumption.

Comment: Ended up being el._id but it works. However, is it the best choice to put the function in handleClick??

Comment: This could be improved by using the functional version of `setGroups`, which prevents setting the state based on stale data. `setGroups(groups => groups.filter(el => el.id !== groupId))`